# AngularJS : Can't inject $stateParams into config

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access properties on the stateParams object in a router config file but I'm getting errors whenever I try to import the $stateParams service.

```
 (function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('propertyDetails')
        .config([
            '$stateProvider',
            '$stateParams',
            routeConfig
        ]);

    function routeConfig($stateProvider, $stateParams) {
        console.log($stateParams)
    }
})();
```

`$stateProvider` gets imported without any issues but for `stateParams` I get this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module propertyDetails due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateParams
```

Comment: you don't need to inject it, you can just write `controller: function ($stateParams) {...}` or anything else you need it for (for each `state`)

Comment: If I write it in directly it comes up as undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, since config function runs in the configuration phase [when no services are available](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Here is an illustration from the docs:

[image]

There is something wrong with your approach. Why do you ever need to directly access `$stateParams` in the module `config` block? You can inject it into controller when defining states like:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('propertyDetails')
        .config([
            '$stateProvider',
            routeConfig
        ]);

    function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('property.detail', {
                url: "/property/:propertyId",
                templateUrl: 'property.detail.html',
                controller: function ($stateParams) {
                    console.log($stateParams);
                }
            });
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly inject to the main function of your controller

```
angular
        .module('propertyDetails')
        .controller('TestController', TestController)

TestController.$inject = ['$scope',  '$stateParams'];
function TestController($scope, $stateParams) {
//your code
}
```